# Retorno de conexão XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
httpGet("www.xxxx.com.br/");
```

Como faço para testar se a URL Está ou não ATIVA? Por exemplo, ele tenta entrar nesse endereço, se ele não conseguir ele me retorna um Alert "Site fora do AR"?

Answer (score 4):

É bem simples, basta verificar a propriedade `status` da requisição AJAX. Por exemplo:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open('GET', url, false);
xmlHttp.send();

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if ( xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlHttp.status === 200 ) {
    // Continuação do código
  } else {
    alert('Fora do ar');
  }
};
```

Comment: Obrigado @Júnior, vou testar aqui e já marco a resposta....qualquer duvida te aviso!

Answer (score 4):

Por **ativa** você quer dizer **se houve alguma resposta**?

Se sim, a maneira correta é utilizando um tempo de *timeout*.

A propriedade [timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#timeout) do objeto XMLHttpRequest aceita um número em millisegundos de timeout, e a propriedade [ontimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#ontimeout) é a (função) chamada quando este tempo é atingido.

```
xmlHttp.timeout = 10000; //10 segundos
xmlHttp.ontimeout = function() { alert('Parece que o site está fora do ar...'); }
```

---

**status diferente de 200 não quer dizer o site está fora do ar!**

Toda a [família 200 do protocolo HTTP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo%3aLista_de_c%C3%B3digos_de_status_HTTP#2xx_Sucesso) (201, 202, 203, 204...) têm significado de que a requisição foi bem sucedida.

Além de as respostas de redirecionamento ([família 300](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo%3aLista_de_c%C3%B3digos_de_status_HTTP#3xx_Redirecionamento)) poderem também ser perfeitamente válidas (por exemplo o status 304 é retornado quando é utilizado o cache do browser e não uma nova requisição).

Mesmo os status de erro ([400](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo%3aLista_de_c%C3%B3digos_de_status_HTTP#4xx_Erro_de_cliente) e [500](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo%3aLista_de_c%C3%B3digos_de_status_HTTP#5xx_outros_erros)) não siginificam *que o servidor está fora do ar*. Estar fora do ar significa *não responder*; e para determinar isso utilizamos o tempo chamado de *timeout*.